# Codemagic iOS Code signing - Unable to load bundle identifiers

Tags: codemagic, app-store-connect-api

I have configured Codemagic with an App Store Connect Key and everything works correctly, now I have tried to add a second key and I am having this problem

```
Unable to load bundle identifiers
    
Loading bundle identifiers for KEYNAME failed. This request is forbidden for security reasons - Unable to find a team with the given Content Provider ID 'ISSUERID' to which you belong.
```

How can I solve the problem? The second key is configured well on App Store Connect, I can't figure out what the problem is.

Thanks for your help